# How to create lock screen customization on iPad with iPadOS 16 like in iOS 16

Tags: ipad, ipados, customization

I recently updated my iPad to iPadOS 16 with the intention of trying out the new lock screen customization capabilities. However after following the [Apple support page for "Personalize Your iPhone Lock Screen"](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/personalize-your-iphone-lock-screen-iph4d0e6c351/ios) I cannot seem to get the customization settings to show up.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Long pressing does not reveal the Customize button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to various articles, lock screen customization available on iOS 16 is not available on iPads running iPadOS16. This feature was left out of the update.

Articles:

- Apple Discussion Forum: ["Can I edit iPadOS 16 Lock Screen?"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254328978)
- macrumors.com: ["iOS 16 Lock Screen Customizations Not Coming to iPadOS 16"](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/06/06/no-lock-screen-customization-features-on-ipados-16/)
- Onsitego.com : ["iPadOS 16 Will Not Get iOS 16 Lock Screen Customisation: Here’s What It Misses Out On"](https://onsitego.com/blog/ipados-16-no-lock-screen-customisation/)
- 9to5mac.com: ["iPadOS 16 beta 1 has secret debug menu that enables custom lock screen – sort of"](https://9to5mac.com/2022/06/10/ipados-16-debug-menu-custom-lock-screen/)